# proof of local maximum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If we have a sequence of real numbers $[a_1, a_2,..., a_n]$, then this sequence has got a p-step local maximum at the $kth$ position, if max {1, k-p} $\le$ m $\le$ min {n, k+p}, $a_m \le a_k$.

Now, how to prove that a finite sequence of real numbers has got at least one p-step maximum?

Comment: Why not choose the maximum of the finite sequence????

Comment: the question has got the expression 'p-step maximum'!

Comment: Well, the maximum must be a $p$-step maximum, which proves your assertion!

Comment: Why not just take $p=n$? Then $k-p\le 0$ and $k+p\gt n$ so we just get that $1\le m\le n$ which is vacuously true.

Answer (score 1):

A finite sequence has at least one greatest  element, that is, an element $a_k$ such that $a_k\ge a_m$ for all $m$. This $a_k$ satisfies the definition of  a $p$-step maximum, for any $p$. (Or, what copper.hat said).